# Test uri with included space character yields "current node list is empty"

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

Attempts to test a uri with an included space character fail.  The uri is `/contact/latestReport/Most recent`. Each of the trials below results in

> The current node list is empty

Trials include:

- `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/contact/latestReport/Most recent');`
- `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/contact/latestReport/Most%20recent');`
- `$uri = urlencode('/contact/latestReport/Most recent'); 
  $crawler = $client->request('GET', urldecode($uri));`

Edit:
Here's the actual test code.  Its previously working version contained only `/contact/latestReport`.  Adding `/Most recent` yielded the error in the test only. [The client requested a very similar report so there are now `/Most recent` and `/FY to date` versions.] In the dev & prod environments `/contact/latestReport/Most recent` yields the expected result.

```
public function testLatestContacts()
{
    $crawler = $this->login();
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/contact/latestReport/Most recent');
    $truckee = $this->fixtures->getReference('truckee')->getId();
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();
    $form['select_center[center]'] = $truckee;
    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("No contacts found")')->count());
}
```

Comment: you need to show your code. Using `%20` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geez!  Once again bit by not clearing the test cache.  Test works when cache is cleared.